# Chrome stalled about 1 second for initial loading of the site, but zero later on freshring

Tags: google-chrome, timing

I have running a site serve both via https and http.

The issue only happen when access via https, steps are

1. open a chrome, first time to load the only single site in HTTPS, chrome stall this inital connection about 1second.
2. however any immediate subsequent refreshing the same page, only have zero to couples of milliseconds, can ignore.
3. put aside the page(don't interact with it, for a short while, may few minutes),  then pick it up to refresh it,  it will repeat from step #1(stall about 1 second, followed by any immediate refresh almost zero stalling)

This only happen when access the site by HTTPS,  don't have this kind of issue when access by HTTP(always almost zero stalling).

Issue only seen in Chrome browser, but not safari and firefox(there is almost no stalled time), all tested in Mac OS

Would any one help to give some idea please? why the first loading introduce 1 second stalling? how to reduce that stalling time please
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDfkn.png)

sorry, this is really hard to explain the issue

Comment: I think i found the cause now, i was using a self-signed certificate for https connection, though i add it to browser exception list to trust it,  it looks like chrome is being more strict on this(than others ), after switching to a trust CA signed cert. The chrome stalled time almost reduce few millseconds for all request now, i am happy to close this question now.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the cause now, i was using a self-signed certificate for https connection, though i add it to browser exception list to trust it, it looks like chrome is being more strict on this(than others ), after switching to a trust CA signed cert. The chrome stalled time reduce to jus few millseconds for all request now, i am happy to close this question now